# Non-Recursive version of f() in Java

Tags: java

```
public static int f(int a){
        if(a==0) return 0;
        if(a==1) return 1;
        return (f(a-1) + f(a-2));
}
```

Is there a non-recursive way of doing this?

Comment: yes you can, Using loop.

Comment: In short:  yes.  Question:  What approaches have you taken to solve it non-recursively?

Comment: With `a < 0` this recursion becomes infinite.